# How to display rCharts plots in a Jupyter notebooks?

Tags: r, rcharts, jupyter

I am trying to render a rCharts plot in a jupyter notebook. The code snippet runs without any error but the output is not displayed.

Sample code snippet,

```
require(rCharts)
r1 <- rPlot(mpg ~ wt | am + vs, data = mtcars, type = "point", color = "gear")
r1$print
```